# iPhone/iPad stretchy, resizable buttons - subclassing UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, resize, uibutton

I want to be able to make custom buttons which have an image background using a scale9 type background image meaning the width of the button can be dynamic. I have seen example on the web of people doing this on a per button basis but it seems to me that wouldn't it be better to create a new object which subclasses UIButton which you can then use in Interface Designer as the class for any custom button (round rect button set to custom).

Here is what I have so far.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LargeButton : UIButton {
}

@end

#import "LargeButton.h"


@implementation LargeButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
 if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

  self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 170.0, 48.0);

  // Center the text vertically and horizontally
  self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
  self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBigPurple.png"];

  // Make a stretchable image from the original image
  UIImage *stretchImage = 
  [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

  // Set the background to the stretchable image
  [self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  // Make the background color clear
  //self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 }
 return self;
}

@end
```

This doesn't however seems to work. When I run this im simulator I see the button text but the button has no background. I have placed a breakpoint and I know its running and check the console and have no errors.

Can someone help? fix this or is my way of thinking wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that images in UIButtons have to have certain RGB image standards.  If you don't have an image that adheres to that, it won't display.  Don't remember where though so I'm not much help :(

Comment: thanks for the feedback. The image work if I set it on the button as the background without subclassing UIButton and setting my button to use my object so I don't think its an image problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself. For those who are interested.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface LargeButton : UIButton {
}

@end

#import "LargeButton.h"


    @implementation LargeButton

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
        UIImage *greenBalloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBigPurple.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0];
        [self setBackgroundImage:greenBalloon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    @end
```

Simple but effective.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I just needed to find out which method was called.